How can I find the integration domain for this question?
Calculate the volume of the solid bounded by the planes $z=-1, z=x+4$ and the surface $(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}} = x^2-y^2$.
So I have tried to find the domain of the integral by changing to cillyndrical coordinates, but I'm stuck trying to imagine how the volume will be define in the plane $XYZ$, cause we have a surface in the $XY$, but also the planes in $Z$.
My direction is that:  $(r, \theta, z): \begin{cases} 0 \leq r \leq \cos{2 \theta} \\ ? ~ \leq \theta \leq ~ ? \\ -1 \leq z \leq r\cos(\theta) + 4 &\end{cases} $.
Am I in the right direction? And if I'm, how can I find the domain of $\theta$ ? Thx.

You are on the right track. Consider that
$$(x^2+y^2)^{\frac{3}{2}} = x^2-y^2$$
implies that $x^2-y^2$ must be strictly nonnegative. This means you're looking for where
$$\cos2\theta \geq 0$$
Can you proceed? Extra Hint: The $\theta$'s need not be connected, and can be multiple disjoint intervals.

I tried : $ \theta \in \left[-\frac{\pi}{4}, : \frac{\pi}{4}\right]$ and the integral would be
$\int _{\frac{-\pi }{4}}^{\frac{\pi }{4}}\int _0^{cos\left(2\theta \right)}\int _{-1}^{4+rcos\left(\theta \right)}rdzdrd\theta ::::$

@Angelo that is not the entire volume.

So what would it be then? what part am I missing?
